# How can I flush a variable value to main memory?

Tags: java

I have a boolean variable 'isInitialized' that the main thread will set to 'true'. And I want all subsequent threads to see it as true.

I therefore want to flush the variable to main memory after I set it to true.

I can use volatile/AtomicBoolean, but I find there's no need since I only really change its value once at program initialization.

How can I do that in Java?

Comment: You should look into [`AtomicBoolean`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html).

Comment: AtomicBoolean is essentially volatile in this case

Comment: `volatile` is practical here but it depends on what you're doing.  Are you creating a singleton?

Comment: @Makoto sort of, when program starts I initialize an enum. This enum will be used by everyone.

Comment: "but I find there's no need since I only really change its value once at program initialization". Show the initialization code.

Comment: Enums are guaranteed constant by the JVM, so the instance of the enum is at least guaranteed.  I'm not clear as to why you need `volatile` yet, though.

Comment: If you set it ever, even once you need to make it `final` or `volatile` to be sure of seeing the change on other threads.

Comment: One way to avoid this type of setting/check is to use a static initialisation block which handles this for you.

Comment: It's not really relevant. I need to run code only once, at initialzation, and all subsequent calls after that should only be used once initialization is complete. So i need a boolean to maintain that initialization is done. Otherwise exception is thrown. I can use volatile, but it's a performance hit, since one initialised the boolean will.nkt change values.

Comment: A volatile read on a value which doesn't change isn't much of a hit i.e. < 1 ns.  If you want to avoid this, use a static initialisation block.

Comment: @PeterLawrey <1ns it's hard to believe that number. Isn't the volatile value is main memory?

Comment: No, the value is consistent across threads. It's *notionally* in main memory but it is in L1/L2 cache after you access it.

Comment: @PeterLawrey interesting, how does the compiler keeps track if the volatile variable value has changed and invalidates the cache of other threads? Any reads on the topic?

Comment: This is done at the hardware level by the L2 cache coherency bus. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_coherence All java does is use a slightly different machine code instruction to load/store the value.